# PySpark Lag function based on condition

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-schema

I am new to PySpark and have been trying a few stuff.

I have a data frame as follows

```
+----------+-----------+
|   Column1|    Column2|
+----------+-----------+
|    VALUE1|      30000|
|    VALUE2|      25000|
|    VALUE3|      20000|
|    VALUE4|      19500|
|    VALUE5|      18100|
+----------+-----------+
```

I want to add a new column such that its value is as per the following formula

```
CurrentRow[Column3] = 
    IF (CurrentRow[Column2] > PreviousRow[Column3]) 
    THEN PreviousRow[Column3]
    ELSE CurrentRow[Column2] * 0.9
```

Example below

```
+----------+------------------+------------------+
|   Column1|           Column2|           Column3|
+----------+------------------+------------------+
|    VALUE1|             30000|             27000|
|    VALUE2|             25000|             22500|
|    VALUE3|             20000|             18000|
|    VALUE4|             19500|             18000|
|    VALUE5|             18100|             18000|
+----------+------------------+------------------+
```

I tried searching for the lag function on the same column that is being updated (withColumn) but could not succeed

Comment: Did you investigate the usage of the pyspark lag function? Can you post any code you have tried already?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Major challenge that I am facing is that I cannot access Column3 while creating the same, which I guess is not possible using DataFrames.

Comment: @AlexandreJuma I tried using the following code but got the wrong result. 


`w = Window.orderBy(F.col('Column2').desc())`

`df = df.withColumn("temp_column", F.col('Column2') * F.lit(0.9))`

`df.withColumn("Column3", F.when(F.col('Column2') >= F.lit(0.9) * F.lag('Column2)', 1).over(w), F.lag('temp_column', 1).over(w)).otherwise(0.9 * F.col('Column2')) ).show() `